# override the submit function of the user_register form in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am working on a module that connects Drupal to an external Web Service.
When a user registers, I want him to register in the web service and not in Drupal.
I want to override the submit function that is called when the user_register form is submitted.

I already use  $form['#submit'], but its not working.

Any other solution? I am using drupal7.

I used like that

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
$form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('Full name'); // perform other changes here 
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_submit' 
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?, the way to do this is using $form['#submit']

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_submit'
```

you are not actually overriding the submit module. You are saying after executing the submit function created by all other modules(which were run before mine), also execute my function `mymodule_user_register_form_submit`

If you want to override the submit function use something like `$form['#submit'] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_submit'` which will make sure that your function is the only function that will get executed.

Comment: I am not finding any difference with my and your approach. 

My Approach $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_submit' 


Your approach $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_submit'

Where should i use that?

Comment: Oops sorry my bad. Change $form['#submit'][] to $form['#submit'] = In the first thing you are adding the array but where is in the second one it will be the only one value.